# Formatting regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words

```
wordlist = ['hypothesis' , 'test' , 'results' , 'total']
```

I have a sentence

```
sentence = "These tests will benefit in the long run."
```

I want to check to see if the words in `wordlist` are in the sentence. I know that you could check to see if they are substrings in the sentence using:

```
for word in wordlist:
    if word in sentence:
        print word
```

However, using substrings, I start to match words that are not in `wordlist`, for example here `test` will appear as a substring in sentence even though it is `tests` that is in the sentence. I could solve my problem by using regular expressions, however, is it possible to implement regular expressions in a way to be formatted with each new word, meaning if I want to see if the word is in the sentence then:

```
for some_word_goes_in_here in wordlist:
    if re.search('.*(some_word_goes_in_here).*', sentence):
         print some_word_goes_in_here
```

so in this case the regular expression would interpret `some_word_goes_in_here` as the pattern that needs to be searched for and not the value of `some_word_goes_in_here`. Is there a way to format the input of `some_word_goes_in_here` so that the regular expression searches for the value of `some_word_goes_in_here`?

Comment: If you have a better solution, I am eager to listen to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', sentence):
```

`\b` are word boundaries which will match between your word and a non word character (a word character is any letter, digit or underscore).

For instance,

```
>>> import re
>>> wordlist = ['hypothesis' , 'test' , 'results' , 'total']
>>> sentence = "The total results for the test confirm the hypothesis"
>>> for word in wordlist:
...     if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', sentence):
...             print word
...
hypothesis
test
results
total
```

With your string:

```
>>> sentence = "These tests will benefit in the long run."
>>> for word in wordlist:
...     if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', sentence):
...          print word
...
>>>
```

Nothing is printed

Comment: @kolonel I used a different string, but let me put yours in a bit

Comment: @MartijnPieters I should have changed it ^^;. Did it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry why does it fail if I replace r'\b' with '\b'?

Comment: @kolonel It's because `\b` is the backspace character. You'll have to pass the raw string `\b` (or else, you use `re.search('\\b' + word + '\\b', sentence):`) to the regex for it to mean the word boundary.

Comment: @kolonel You can call me 'Jerry'. You're welcome! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Use `\b` word boundaries to test for the words:

```
for word in wordlist:
    if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence):
        print '{} matched'.format(word)
```

but you could also just split the sentence into separate words. Using a set for the word list would make the test more efficient:

```
words = set(wordlist)
if words.intersection(sentence.split()):
    # no looping over `words` required.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> wordlist = ['hypothesis' , 'test' , 'results' , 'total']
>>> sentence = "These tests will benefit in the long run."
>>> for word in wordlist:
...     if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence):
...         print '{} matched'.format(word)
... 
>>> words = set(wordlist)
>>> words.intersection(sentence.split())
set([])
>>> sentence = 'Lets test this hypothesis that the results total the outcome'
>>> for word in wordlist:
...     if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), sentence):
...         print '{} matched'.format(word)
... 
hypothesis matched
test matched
results matched
total matched
>>> words.intersection(sentence.split())
set(['test', 'total', 'hypothesis', 'results'])
```

Comment: I was considering using `re.escape` and decided against it since _words_ don't need that escaping.  In a more general case it is a good advice.

Comment: @MartjinPieters I think splitting the sentence into words could introduce error, as finding boundaries between words is not really a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this:

```
words = "hypothesis test results total".split()
# ^^^ but you can use your literal list if you prefer that
for word in words:
  if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % (word,), sentence):
    print word
```

You can even speed this up by using a single regexp:

```
for foundWord in re.findall(r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(words) + r'\b', sentence):
  print foundWord
```